# What blocks make note blocks sound different?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

If you can, please label what type of sound each block makes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This information is from the [minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Note_Block).

- Wood: Bass
- Sand, Gravel, Concrete powder: Snare drum
- Glass, Sea Lantern: Hi-hat
- Stone, Netherrack, Nylium, Obsidian, Quartz, Sandstone, Ores: Kick bass
- Gold Block: Glockenspiel
- Clay: Flute
- Packed ice: Chimes
- Wool: Guitar
- Bone Block: Xylophone
- Iron Block: Vibraphone
- Soul Sand: Cowbell
- Pumpkin: Didgeridoo
- Emerald Block: Chiptune
- Haybale: Banjo
- Glowstone: Electric Piano
- Anything else: Piano